# Is it possible to change/replace the custom function argument in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.2, preference

I just want to change/replace the custom function arguments, not constructor arguments.

This is third party module function, which have wrong argument.

```
public function addAttachment(\Fooman\EmailAttachments\Model\Api\AttachmentInterface $attachment)
{
    $this->message->createAttachment(
        $attachment->getContent(),
        $attachment->getMimeType(),
        $attachment->getDisposition(),
        $attachment->getEncoding(),
        $this->encodedFileName($attachment->getFilename())
    );
}
```

I want to replace argument from

> \Fooman\EmailAttachments\Model\Api\AttachmentInterface $attachment

to

> \VladimirPopov\WebForms\Model\Api\AttachmentInterface $attachment

Now, function looks like below:

```
public function addAttachment(\VladimirPopov\WebForms\Model\Api\AttachmentInterface $attachment)
{
    $this->message->createAttachment(
        $attachment->getContent(),
        $attachment->getMimeType(),
        $attachment->getDisposition(),
        $attachment->getEncoding(),
        $this->encodedFileName($attachment->getFilename())
    );
}
```

I have tried to overwrite this function by preference through the di.xml, But it's generating below error:

```
  [Exception]                                                                  
  Warning: Declaration of Vendor\Modulename\Model\Preference\Mail\Transp  
  ortBuilder::addAttachment(VladimirPopov\WebForms\Model\Api\AttachmentInterf  
  ace $attachment) should be compatible with VladimirPopov\WebForms\Model\Mai  
  l\TransportBuilder::addAttachment(Fooman\EmailAttachments\Model\Api\Attachm  
  entInterface $attachment) in 
  app/code/Vendor/Modulename/Model/Preference/Mail/TransportBuilder.php   
  on line 28
```

I have taken help from this article : https://alanstorm.com/magento_2_object_manager_argument_replacement/
But, here i got about only to change constructor arguments.

I don't know, is it possible for not? Please suggest.

Comment: For just workaround you can use File Base overriding, try this until find proper solution